# Django: How to remove space between project urls and app urls?

Tags: django

It is Python 2.7 & Django 1.1. my project urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from main.main_config import main_config
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^%sactivation/' % main_config.url_prefix, include('activation.urls', namespace='activation')),
                       url(r'^%sac6590e0/' % main_config.url_prefix, include('activation.urls', namespace='activation')),
                       url(r'^%sreport/' % main_config.url_prefix, include('report.urls', namespace='report')),
                       url(r'^%srpccb4a9/' % main_config.url_prefix, include('report.urls', namespace='report')),
                       url(r'^%scloudctl/' % main_config.url_prefix, include('cloudctl.urls', namespace='cloudctl')),
                       url(r'^%sct8a8d6a/' % main_config.url_prefix, include('cloudctl.urls', namespace='cloudctl')),
                       url(r'^%sadmin/data/' % main_config.url_prefix, include('explorer.urls')),
                       url(r'^%sadmin/' % main_config.url_prefix, include(admin.site.urls)),
                       url(r'^%s' % main_config.url_prefix, include('main.urls', namespace='main')),
                       )
```

The app's urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from main import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       # url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
                       url(r'checkConnection', views.checkConnection, name='checkConnection'),
                       url(r'c94372af', views.checkConnection, name='checkConnection'),
                       url(r'^get_data_everyday', views.get_data, name='get_data_everyday'),
                       url(r'downloads/(?P<color>[yb]{1})/(?P<placeID>[0-9]{4})/$', views.downloads, name='downloads'),
                       url(r'suggestion/(?P<ver1>[0-9])/(?P<ver2>[0-9])/(?P<ver3>[0-9])/$', views.suggestion,
                           name='suggestion')
                       )
```

It was working prefer. But after a server restart. now I am getting the problem as the picture shows. There is spaces between urls. and it stops working.

Anyone can help? Thanks.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IXOz.png)

Comment: These spaces are *not* in the real URLs, that is just for *formatting* of `include`s

Answer (score 0):

The spaces are *not* in the real URLs, the spaces are only used for *formatting* the error message, to make it more clear that there was an include.

The reason the url did not work was because your url has `keypad/checkConntion`, whereas the url is `keypad/checkConnection/`, so with an `ec` between `Conn` and `tion`.

You might want to use the [**`{% url … %}`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url) to avoid errors in the raw URLs.

> It is Python 2.7 & Django 1.1

I would strongly advise to upgrade. Python-2.x is [no longer supported since January 1, 2020](https://pythonclock.org/), and Django-1.1 is not supported anymore since 2012 if I recall correctly.

Comment: Thank you, Sir. finally I got it running again by restoring the whole ubuntu system to 2 days ago.  But I still have no clue what caused the problem.

Comment: @Wind: as said, you have a typo in one of your templates. It hits `keypad/checkConntion`, but that does not exists, it is `keypad/checkConnection`. Resetting will not make any difference at all.